# ios change view on button click

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

I am new in ios development i know pretty simple , i want to change view on button click 
this is my code  i create Tabbed Application ,storyboard flow is

> TabView Controller-> Navigation Controller
>   ->HomeViewController->Navigation Controller->ShopViewController

Code snippet:

```
 @implementation HomeViewController

 @synthesize users;
 - (IBAction)shopButton:(id)sender {
       NSLog(@"hi sachin");
       NSLog(@"INSIDE Shops");

      ShopViewController *cvc = [[ShopViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ShopViewController" bundle:nil];
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:cvc animated:YES];
  }
```

Its showing an error like this:

```
    Pacific1[2556:70b] hi sachin
    2014-02-25 16:34:49.374 Pacific1[2556:70b] INSIDE Shops
    2014-02-25 16:34:49.632 Pacific1[2556:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
    exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load
    NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle (loaded)' with name 'ShopViewController''
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "ShopViewController" xib does not exists. See:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught
exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load
NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle (loaded)' with name 'ShopViewController''
```

> "Could not load
>       NIB in bundle"

If you're using storyboards you may want to instantiate the view like this:

```
ShopViewController *cvc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ShopViewController"];
```

Not 100% on that, but someone else may be able to point you in the right direction as I don't use storyboards.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a storyboard, you should instantiate your view controller using the **`instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`** method.

Example:

```
ShopViewController *viewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ShopViewController"];
```

Make sure that the **`identifier`** is correct. It's under the `Identity Inspector` tab in `Interface Builder`. It's called `Storyboard ID`. You can give it any unique name that you want. Also make sure that story board name matches the name of your storyboard (without file extension).

Then:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: its show other error:Pacific1[2904:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'MainStoryboard' in bundle NSBundle </Users/mokshjuneja/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/2595D8F8-2CA9-41F8-B419-8C297B2AED5F/Pacific1.app> (loaded)'

Answer (score 0):

```
ShopViewController *cvc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"youstoryboardID"];
```

If still it,s not navigating than in story board select `MainViewcontroller` and click on **Editor**>**Embed In** in that select `NavigationController`.

I think it will work.